# How to get tapped marker's title in Google map sdk for iOS?

Tags: ios6, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google map sdk for iOS (Version 1.1.2 ) in my app.
I have multiple marker on map.
After tapping particular marker info i have to call another view which contains detail of that place.

I know in which method i have to code.
It is in

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(id<GMSMarker>)marker
```

but,How I get title string of tapped marker ?

Help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be able to just use:

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView 
    didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(id<GMSMarker>)marker
{
    NSString* title = marker.title;
    ...
}
```